# Pointwise and uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x}{x+e^{-nx}}$ $\quad$ $x\in R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

How can I prove pointwise and uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x}{x+e^{-nx}}$ $\quad$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

uniform convergence: the pointwise convergence is on $E=(-\infty,0]$.

$f_n(x)={\frac{x}{x+e^{-nx}}}$

sup$_{E}|{\frac{x}{x+e^{-nx}}}|=f_n(\frac{-1}{n})={\frac{1}{1-ne}}$ general term of a divergent series.So there is not uniform convergent in E.
But if I consider intervals as $(-\infty,a],a<0$ there is uniform convergence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Series is not even point wise convergent . Look at $x=1$.

Comment: @Giulia B can you sugggest where is mistake for downvoting

Answer (score 1):

You can only try to use Leibnitz criterion if $x<0$ because otherwise $|a_n|$ is not decreasing and convergent to zero. In any case, for $x >0$, the series is divergent as the general term does not go to zero.

Comment: For $x<0$ do I study absolute convergence?

Comment: Sure, for $x \leq 0$ you go through all the normal steps.

Comment: For $x=0$ the series is obviously convergent (and the sum is zero) and for $x<0$, using the fact that $\left|\frac{x}{x+e^{-nx}}\right| < e^{nx}$ you can prove absolute convergence.

Comment: the uniform convergence is right?

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, the general term is asymptotic to $(-1)^n$ (the exponential vanishes) and the series diverges.

For $x=0$ the general term is $0$.

For $x<0$, the exponential dominates and the general term is asymptotic to $xe^{nx}$, and the series converges.